# How to format the number in razor view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following code:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccName)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccRaseed)
         </td>
      </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to format `AccRaseed` value as:

```
@(string.Format("{0:N}", item.AccRaseed))
```

And I tried by:

```
@item.AccRaseed.ToString("N")
```

But that doesn't work. What I need exactly if I have "1175950.25" I need it as "1,175,950.25"

Thanks

Comment: Simplest way is `@item.AccRaseed.ToString("n2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following format:

```
@($"{item.AccRaseed:n2}")
```

---

Some additional information about formatting is here: [Double.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-7.0)

Comment: I got: cannot implicitly convert type object to string

Comment: @M.J: How the `AccRaseed` is declared?

Comment: public string AccRaseed { get; set; }

Comment: @M.J: It should be, for example,  `double` then you can use format. You can't use `ToString()` on `string` type. Don't make a sense.

Comment: it's working now, thank you, can I ask if that is the best way to format or if there is another way?

Comment: @M.J: I would create an extension method that can be used in all places where I need conversion to specific format. Inside this method you can apply required regional setting and so on...

Comment: The string interpolation is unnecessary. I prefer `@item.AccRaseed.ToString("n2")`